# Identify MKPointAnnotation in mapView

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkpointannotation

I have at least 100 diferents Points ... how can associate each point with the position in my 'listOfPoints' assigning a tag in the position associated in  viewForAnnotation .

Here i add my Points, some events will have the same title.

```
var listOfPoints : Array<Events> = [] // List Of all events

//add points to map
    for (index, mPoints) in enumerate(listOfPoints) {

        var point: MKPointAnnotation! = MKPointAnnotation()
        var location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: mPoints.latitude, longitude: mPoints.longitude)
        point.coordinate = location
        point.title = mPoints.name
        point.subtitle = mPoints.address
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(point)
    }

//Draw custom pin in the map

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    print("ffff");

    var identifier = "CustomAnnotation"


    if annotation.isKindOfClass(MKPointAnnotation) {
        var pin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier)

        if pin == nil {
            pin = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            pin.tag = tagPosition; // here
            pin.image = UIImage(named: "mapa_pin")
            pin.centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -10)
            pin.canShowCallout = true

            var pointTitle = pin!.annotation.title! as String


            // Callout
            var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.DetailDisclosure) as UIButton
            pin!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = button

            var image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "mapa_pin"))
            pin!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = image


        } else {
            pin!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pin
    }

    return nil

}

// Print the position 
    func  mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
        println(view.tag);
    }
```

How can associated this tag with the position on my 'listOfPoints'

```
pin.tag = tagPosition;
```

or is there another way?

Comment: If you just need tag, then in your "viewForAnnotation" API, find the index of "annotation" in "listOfPoints" and set it.

Comment: @gagarwal, That would not work because the code creates annotations of type MKPointAnnotation _from_ the objects in listOfPoints which are of type Events (they are completely separate objects).  The best solution is to use a custom class like matt's answer says.

Comment: I agree with matt's answer though you might consider making your Events object _itself_ implement the MKAnnotation protocol.  That way, your annotation objects will already be Events so you will not need any linking properties or lookups afterwards.

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra: Do not confuse the annotation model objects (like MKPointAnnotation) with their views (like MKAnnotationView).  They are completely different classes and completely different things.  The answer is talking about the model objects -- not the views.

Answer (score 7):

I think that is easy and im doing this in an app my.

I customize a class for Annotation from MKAnnotation:

```
import MapKit
import AddressBook

class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation
{
    let identifier : String
    let title: String
    let subtitle: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let color: MKPinAnnotationColor


    init(identifier: String, title: String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, color: MKPinAnnotationColor)
    {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.color = color

        super.init()
    }

    func mapItem() -> MKMapItem
    {
        let addressDictionary = [String(kABPersonAddressStreetKey): subtitle]
        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate, addressDictionary: addressDictionary)

        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = title

        return mapItem
    }
}
```

Now you can use the field identifier from class MyAnnotation in your points:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!
{
    if let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation
    {
        let identifier = annotation.identifier
        var view: MKPinAnnotationView

        if let dequeuedView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        {
            view = dequeuedView
            view.annotation = annotation
        }
        else
        {
            view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
            view.canShowCallout = true
            view.calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
            view.animatesDrop = true
            view.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as! UIView
            view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.ContactAdd) as! UIView
            view.pinColor = annotation.color
            //view.image
            //MKAnnotationView 32 x 29
        }
        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

If you don't understand you can red this excelente article:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial

Comment: This needs an update for Swift 3. If I get it to work I'll post it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using a plain vanilla built-in MKPointAnnotation. It has no `tag` property. You need to define your own MKAnnotation class (i.e. a class that adopts the MKAnnotation protocol). That way, it can have any properties you like.

Comment: can you give me an example? . I need get the position tag of the pin.

Comment: And here is my example of a basic custom annotation class written in Swift: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch21p744maps/ch34p1008maps/MyAnnotation.swift Adding a `tag` property to that is obvious and trivial.

Comment: This example does not work for me, the click  are based on the title of the pin, I have many pins with the same title

Comment: Ok, if i use  custom MKAnnotation,  I could get the tags I need. now I understand.

Comment: How can i get the new var in the viewForAnnotation ?

Answer (score 2):

My very easy solution on Objective-C

.h file:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface mapMKPointAnnotation : MKPointAnnotation

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger tag;

@end
```

and create object with tag:

```
mapMKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[mapMKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setTag:1];
```

next get tag in method:

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

static NSString *SFAnnotationIdentifier = @"SFAnnotationIdentifier";
    mapMKPointAnnotation *mMKPAnn = (mapMKPointAnnotation *) annotation;
    NSString *img = [mMKPAnn tag] == 0 ? @"map_icon" : @"map_icon_active";
```

Comment: This is the best answer!